# How to send to logs elastic search and have buffer turned on

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have a basic web api application, on errors it sends logs directly to elastic search. I am currently using serilog event sink to send logs directly to elastic search.

program.cs

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, configuration) =>
{
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration);
});
```

appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft.Hosting": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
    "EasyNetQ": "Warning",
    "Elastic.Apm": "Information"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Elasticsearch",
    "Args": {
      "nodeUris": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.es.eu-west-1.aws.found.io",
      "indexFormat": "test.standard-{0:yyyy.MM}",
      "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
      "batchAction": "Create",
      "overwriteTemplate": true,
      "templateName": "test",
      "typeName": null,
      "bufferBaseFilename": "C:/Temp/docker-elk-serilog-web-buffer",
      "bufferFileSizeLimitBytes": 5242880,
      "bufferLogShippingInterval": 5000,
      "bufferRetainedInvalidPayloadsLimitBytes": 5000,
      "bufferFileCountLimit": 31,
      "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=ApiKey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "customFormatter": "Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog.EcsTextFormatter, Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog"
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [
  "FromLogContext",
  "WithMachineName",
  "WithEnvironmentUserName",
  "WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo",
  "WithExceptionDetails"
]
```

}

if I remove anything the appsettings buffer arguments, I am able to send logs directly to serilog. May I ask how do I have buffer and elastic search sink

Comment: If you want to directly send to Elasticsearch what would be the purpose of that buffer then?

Comment: @Ralf contingency incase sending directly failed.